# extra array string shows up out of nowhere using each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

1.[Original Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGyey/340/)

2.[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGyey/339/)

I got a weird issue when using a bar chart plugin from this [site](http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/). 
Can anyone figure out why the array from the first `div.largearea` shows up out of nowhere at the bottom left hand corner in the second example?

[image]

It doesn't have any issue at all when it only has one `div.largearea` on the page, as you can see in the first example.

HTML:

```
<div class="get" data-stats="10.3,'1','#222222'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="15.2,'2','#7D252B'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="13.1,'3','#EB9781'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="16.3,'4','#FFD2B5'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="14.5,'5','#4A4147'"></div></div>
<div class="largearea">
<div class="exampleSimple"></div>

<div class="get" data-stats="10.3,'Nov','#222222'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="15.2,'Dec','#7D252B'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="13.1,'Oct','#EB9781'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="16.3,'June','#FFD2B5'"></div>
<div class="get" data-stats="14.5,'May','#4A4147'"></div></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var arrayOfData = [];
    $('.largearea').each(function(){
        var getbar = $(this).find('.get'),
            getpie = $(this).find('.exampleSimple');
            getbar.each(function(){
             var getstats = $(this).data('stats').split(',');
              getstats[1] = getstats[1].replace(/'/g,'');
              getstats[2] = getstats[2].replace(/'/g,'');
              arrayOfData.push(getstats);
            });

        getpie.jqbargraph({
        data: arrayOfData 
    });
  });


});
```

Comment: This plugin doesn't seem to support multiple charts. Please change to another graph plotting tool.

Comment: Have you checked out D3 for what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that as it cannot draw multiple charts to the same div. As you are using a class selector it is trying to draw the same chart on all div's with that class.

If you need to draw multiple charts you could have to render them into different divs and even create a new instance of the chart for each.

It would help to know if you want to draw multiple charts or what you are trying to do